# ¿porque este console.log dentro de la función no aparece pero me dice status 200 en la consola?

Tags: javascript, pug

```html
doctype html
html
    head
        block head
            meta(charset='UTF-8')
            meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
            link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css')
            link(rel='shortcut icon' type='img/png' href='/img/favicon.png')
            link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,700')
            title Natours | #{title}

    body
        include _header

        block content
            h1 This is a placeholder heading

        include _footer

        script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js')
        script(src='/js/mapbox.js')
        script(src='/js/login.js')
```

estoy usando Node y en postman todo funciona bien pero a la hora de hacer click en submit para loggearme no me aparece ni el console.log de mi funcion, es decir no se esta ejecutando la funcion, no me aparece en cosola esta linea `console.log(email, password);` :(

este es mi codigo "vanilla js" del lado del cliente

```js
/* eslint-disable */
const login = async (email, password) => {
  alert();
  console.log(email, password);
};

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  login(email, password);
});
```

y este es el html esta avreviado raro porque esta en formato de pug

```html
extends base 

block content
    main.main
    .login-form
        h2.heading-secondary.ma-bt-lg Log into your account
        form.form
        .form__group
            label.form__label(for='email') Email address
            input#email.form__input(type='email', placeholder='you@example.com', required)
        .form__group.ma-bt-md
            label.form__label(for='password') Password
            input#password.form__input(type='password', placeholder='••••••••', required, minlength='8')
        .form__group
            button.btn.btn--green(type='submit') Login
```

Comment: ¿No falta en tu código pug algo para incluir el código javascript? un `include` o un `script(...)`

Comment: estoy usando un "extends base" en la primera linea, perdon no se porque no puse voy a editar ahora

Comment: el script esta en el archivo base "script(src='/js/login.js')" esta bien enlazado

Comment: ¿El `alert` tampoco aparece? ¿En pug no se le pone etiqueta `name` a los elementos?

Comment: no nada de lo que esta dentro de esa funcion aparece

Comment: Puede estar bien enlazado, pero si no está al final del body, no existirá el form en el momento de la ejecución.Asegúrate de que el script se añade después del block content

Comment: el formulario si se visualiza aparece pero al hacer submit no ejecuta la funcion login espera agrego el codigo del base

Comment: Debe ser un problema de tu formulario o de pug. Acabo de hacer una prueba en  un form normal y funciona bien: `<form>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>` No conozco pug, por lo que no podría decirte más al respecto.

Comment: ¿No deberías identar los `form-group` con respecto al form? Parece que están al mismo nivel.

Comment: si era un problema de indentado en pug :) gracias tal vez necesite repasar pug